# IPP .NET 3.0 SDK Migration Issue: "Could not load type 'Intuit.Ipp.Core.Rest.SyncRestHandler'"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intuit-partner-platform

I'm receiving the following error when I try to create my DataService object.  I recently swapped out the 2.0 SDK for 3.0 and made all the adjustments detailed in the help docs.  Not sure what's going on though.  Any ideas?

"Could not load type 'Intuit.Ipp.Core.Rest.SyncRestHandler' from assembly 'Intuit.Ipp.Core, Version=2.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'"

```
OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = 
new OAuthRequestValidator(QuickBooksToken, 
                          QuickBooksSecretToken, 
                          QuickBooksConsumerKey, 
                          QuickBooksConsumerSecret);

ServiceContext context = 
new ServiceContext(oauthValidator, QuickBooksRealm, IntuitServicesType.QBO);

//Blows up here           
DataService commonService = new DataService(context);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue for me, and it appears to be somewhat working by making DataService plural:

```
DataServices commonService = new DataServices(context);
```

Unfortunately, has an issue a bit further on and limits the functionality. For example, I have errors when attempting to use the query service, which apparently expects DataService (singular).

```
Method not found: 'Void Intuit.Ipp.Core.ServiceContext.UseDataServices()'.
```

If I can find a real answer, I will post it here...

Update:

I made a new bin/ folder, added the new sdk dll files and copied whatever else I needed (dotnetoauth etc,). Some minor changes to my code, and viola, it works.

```
OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);

ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(realmId, IntuitServicesType.QBO, oauthValidator);

DataService commonService = new DataService(context);
```

Comment: Manually stuffing the bin folder with the new DLL's did the trick for me.  Thanks.